# How can I use destructuring of an object correctly

Tags: javascript

I have js code and want use destructuring correctly, how should I do it?

```
const elements = document.forms.myForm.elements;

const artist = elements.artist;
const song = elements.song;

console.log(artist);
console.log(song);
```

Comment: Please post the HTML. You will need .value and your syntax is very old fashioned

Comment: `const { elements: { artist,  song } } = document.forms.myForm`

Comment: This decision is very good for my training, thanks;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really worth it destructuring form elements

But here is a working example

```js
const form = document.getElementById('myForm');

// destructuring mapped values

const [artist,song] = [...form.querySelectorAll("input")].map(inp => inp.value);
console.log(artist,song);

// destructuring elements


const [artistElem,songElem] = form.elements;
console.log(artistElem.value,songElem.value);
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="artist" value="Seal" />
  <input id="song" value="Crazy" />
</form>
```